# How to add column in Dataframe base on the value of other Columns spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have a Data-frame with column "Age" of type String,I want to get a new column containing the range in string format

Range as follows

[-1, 12, 17, 24, 34, 44, 54, 64, 100, 1000]

Input Values for example

```
Age
=====  
-1
12
18
28
38
46
======
```

Output Required

```
  Age    Age-Range
 =====  ========= 
 -1     (-1,12)
 12     (-1,12)
 18     (12-17) 
 28     (24-34)
 38     (34-44)
 46     (44-54) 
======  ==========
```

Any Suggestion or Help is Highly Appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a quick suggestion, I hope it helps:

```scala
case class AgeRange(lowerBound: Int, upperBound: Int) {
  def contains(value: Int): Boolean = value >= lowerBound && value < upperBound
}

val rangeList = List(-1, 12, 17, 24, 34, 44, 54, 64, 100, 1000)
val ranges = rangeList.sliding(2).map((list => AgeRange(list(0), list(1)))).toList
val dataset = Seq("-1", "12", "18", "28", "38", "46").toDS

def findRange(value: Int, ageRanges: List[AgeRange]): Option[AgeRange] = ageRanges.find(_.contains(value))

// With UDF
def myUdf(ageRanges: List[AgeRange]) = udf{
  i: Int => findRange(i, ageRanges) 
}

val result1 = dataset.toDF("age").withColumn("age_range", myUdf(ranges)(col("age").cast("int")))

// With map
val result2 = dataset.map {
  i: String => (i, findRange(i.toInt, ranges))
}.toDF("age", "age_range")
```

Resulting in:

```
result1: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [age: string, age_range: struct<lowerBound: int, upperBound: int>]
result2: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [age: string, age_range: struct<lowerBound: int, upperBound: int>]
+---+---------+
|age|age_range|
+---+---------+
| -1|  [-1,12]|
| 12|  [12,17]|
| 18|  [17,24]|
| 28|  [24,34]|
| 38|  [34,44]|
| 46|  [44,54]|
+---+---------+
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is the simple solution using UDF but you need to manually create a list.

```
//dataframe with column age
val df = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq("-1", "12", "18", "28", "38", "38", "388", "3", "41")).toDF("Age")

val updateUDF = udf((age : String) => {
  val range = Seq(
    (-1, 12, "(-1 - 12)"),
    (12, 17, "(12 - 17)"),
    (17, 24, "(17 - 24)"),
    (24, 34, "(24 - 34)"),
    (34, 44, "(34 - 44)"),
    (44, 54, "(44 - 54)"),
    (54, 64, "(54 - 64)"),
    (64, 10, "(64 - 100)"),
    (100, 1000, "(100- 1000)")
  )
 range.map( value =>  {
   if (age.toInt >= value._1 && age.toInt < value._2) value._3
  else  ""
 }).filter(!_.equals(""))(0)

})

  df.withColumn("Age-Range", updateUDF($"Age")).show(false)

Here is the output:
+---+-----------+
|Age|Age-Range  |
+---+-----------+
|-1 |(-1 - 12)  |
|12 |(12 - 17)  |
|18 |(17 - 24)  |
|28 |(24 - 34)  |
|38 |(34 - 44)  |
|38 |(34 - 44)  |
|388|(100- 1000)|
|3  |(-1 - 12)  |
|41 |(34 - 44)  |
+---+-----------+
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

you can use a udf function as

```
def range = udf((age: String) => {
  val array = Array(-1, 12, 17, 24, 34, 44, 54, 64, 100, 1000)
  val ageInt = age.toInt
  array.filter(i => i <= ageInt).last.toString+"-"+array.filter(i => i > ageInt).head.toString
})
```

and call your dataframe as

```
df.withColumn("Age-Range", range($"Age"))
```

You should have output as

```
+---+---------+
|Age|Age-Range|
+---+---------+
|-1 |-1-12    |
|12 |12-17    |
|18 |17-24    |
|28 |24-34    |
|38 |34-44    |
|46 |44-54    |
+---+---------+
```

The final output is not as you require but should give you more than enough ideas for the right solution.